# printing sum of integer and a char*

Tags: c

Consider the c snippet:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf(2+"Roomy");
    return 0;
}
```

Output given is skipping 1st 2 characters of the string.i.e.,omy

So can anyone explain what is going on with the addition?

Comment: `"Roomy"` is the pointer to string, so by adding two - you're shifting it 2 characters to the right

Comment: `"Roomy"` has type 'array of 6 char'. In most contexts (as in the context of addition) the type is converted to pointer to char (specifically pointer to the `'R'`). Adding `2` to that pointer (`int+ptr` is the same as `ptr+int`) gets a pointer to the 2nd `'o'`. `printf()` does its thing: it prints the characters (except special cases of `'\\'` or `'%'`) in the "format string" *verbatim* until it finds a `'\0'`

Comment: What would you expect to happen?  Why were you trying it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

printf expects a pointer to char. "+2" means shift pointer beyond 2 positions.